# MultiBinding of grid visiblity in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I have a list view Item 
and I want to collapse some of the items in the row of the list
I am using the grid for editing the data template.
I tried to work with multi-binding for the parameter
however I got that "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue"
would be happy for a code example.

if I am using 1 parameter all good.

can someone please explain to me how to use multi-binding 
would be happy with a code example.
thanks.

Working code for 1 parmaeter I can use this code:

```
<ListView x:Name="LVGuiCoreBus" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseDown="LVGui_MouseDown"  Grid.Row="1" >               
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Visibility="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs}}">                                                                                                                              
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>                                                      
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateNTimeStr}"  Foreground="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="{Binding Source,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Background="{ Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConverterBySource}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destination}" Foreground="{Binding Destination,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="4" Background="{ Binding Destination, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConvertorByDestantation}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Module}" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{ Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByModule}}"   />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Controll}" Grid.Column="8"  Background="{ Binding Controll, Converter={StaticResource BackGRoundFilterByControll}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Command}" Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByCommand}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HSCommand}" Grid.Column="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding HSCommand, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByHsCommand}}"   />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data_Str}"  Grid.Column="14"/>                                                                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="CMMenuCopy">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyLine" Header="Copy Line" Click="MCICopyLine_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyText" Header="Copy Only Data Array" Click="MCICopyText_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCIClear" Header="Clear" Click="MCIClear_Click"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

not working code multibinding:

```
<ListView x:Name="LVGuiCoreBus" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseDown="LVGui_MouseDown"  Grid.Row="1" >               
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                  <Grid.Visibility>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConvertorVisibility}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding ElementName="Source" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Destination" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Module" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Controll" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Command" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="HSCommand" Path="Visibility"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Grid.Visibility>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>                                                      
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateNTimeStr}"  Foreground="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="{Binding Source,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Background="{ Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConverterBySource}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destination}" Foreground="{Binding Destination,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="4" Background="{ Binding Destination, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConvertorByDestantation}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Module}" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{ Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByModule}}"   />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Controll}" Grid.Column="8"  Background="{ Binding Controll, Converter={StaticResource BackGRoundFilterByControll}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Command}" Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByCommand}}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HSCommand}" Grid.Column="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding HSCommand, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByHsCommand}}"   />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data_Str}"  Grid.Column="14"/>                                                                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="CMMenuCopy">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyLine" Header="Copy Line" Click="MCICopyLine_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyText" Header="Copy Only Data Array" Click="MCICopyText_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCIClear" Header="Clear" Click="MCIClear_Click"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
 public class MultiValueConvertorVisibility : IMultiValueConverter
 {
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool x = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[0]);
        if (x)
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to set the MultiBinding's Converter.

Comment: what is multibinding convertor? and fo reach element shuold be antoher convertor can you please show exmple

Comment: You already have set a Converter on the Binding inside the MultiBinding. Similar to that, the MultiBinding itself also has a Converter property, where you **have to** assign an object that implements the [IMultiValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: can you please give me a code example

Comment: see the example here http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2154/simple-example-of-multibinding-and-imultivalueconverter-in-mvvm-wrt-wp

Comment: You only have one binding in that multibinding. If that is your intention then you don't need a multibinding at all. You seem to have a lot of converters there. I don't know what they all do but you might find it more practical to put complicated logic and translation in a viewmodel rather than numerous converters.

Comment: I need add more the one binding I just to undestand why it doesn't work and other parametersper first parameters

Comment: I edited question tried to work with MultiValueConvertorVisibility and still issue not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important piece conceptually that you are missing is the `IMultiValueConverter`, because visibility is just one value, at the end of the day, you want your grid to be either visible or not, so you have to tell the multibinding how to compose your multiple values into one.

Here is an example of how to get multi-binding to work:

**The Grid:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MyCustomConvertor"/>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyCustomConvertor}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Visibility"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Visibility>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The **Viewmodel** that you bind to:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region WPF integration properties
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion

        private Visibility _visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility Visibility
        {
            get { return _visibility; }
            set
            {
                _visibility = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Visibility));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the **MultiValueConverter** to convert multiple visibility bindings into one:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (values.Contains(Visibility.Collapsed))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            if (values.Contains(Visibility.Hidden))
            {
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            }

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Into the converter you could place any logic that you see fit, I just imposed a kind of hierarchy on the different visibility types.

Comment: Hey @RubenBohnet Apologies but I don't feel this is correct.  A ViewModel typically shouldn't control view state, in other words, putting Visibility in the ViewModel is considered bad practice.  However, if you do then you can place all the logic in the ViewModel and remove the converter. It needs to be one or the other.  I strongly suggest sticking to the converter for Visibility changes.  A simple IMultiValueConverter should suffice.  Hopefully you take this comment as a suggestion and not strong criticism.  I mean well.  ViewModels should never assume view state or control the view.

Comment: The direct mapping shown here is just to avoid an extra step of abstraction that would add nothing to the answer. One can easily assume that the viewmodel is a node, that contains a bool along the lines of `Active`, which first would be translated by a converter into visibility. 
That example would honor responsibilities in the MVVM model, however I felt it would not help OP understand the answer to his question better.

Comment: Also: Thanks for taking your time to improve my programming!